# how does this Ruby class method get invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a screen cast on [Exporting CSV from a rails app](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel), Ryan Bates presented the following simple code.

I'm trying to figure out how the class method Product::to_csv actually gets invoked on line 5 of ProductController.rb, as it doesn't seem to follow the normal Ruby rules.

**product.rb**

```
1 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base   
2   def self.to_csv(options = {})
3     ...
4   end
5 end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
1 class ProductsController < ApplicationController
2  def index
3    @products = Product.order(:name)
4    respond_to do |format|
5      format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
6      ...
7    end
8  end
9 end
```

Since to_csv is a class method, I'd expect the invocation to look like Product::to_csv().

According to the documentation, @products is an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation. Why do messages sent to an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation cause methods on the Product class object to get invoked? To make it even stranger, renaming to_csv to some arbitrary name in both the the sender and receiver leads to NoMethodError, so maybe there is some magic afoot based on names that begin with to_?

Am I missing something obvious? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just one of the things Rails does. Any class methods automatically become available as "collection" methods, meaning they are available to the relation objects. Scopes and class methods are interchangeable that way.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain the behavior. It would be nice if this was mentioned in the Rails guides or documentation somewhere. Based on your answer, I looked through the source code. If I understand correctly, ActiveRecord::Relations will delegate method calls to the associated class object if it responds to them, then finally to :arel

Comment: If you're interested in exploring this more, I started working on a proof of concept gem that allowed you to separate models from collections. It's called [Herd](https://github.com/beerlington/herd). I haven't done much with it in production, but you can check out the source and see what I had to do in order to ["register" methods](https://github.com/beerlington/herd/blob/master/lib/herd.rb#L20) on the relation classes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that ActiveRecord::Relations also seem to delegate methods to the resulting Array object (triggering a database fetch if necessary). It will first look for a class method on the associated ActiveRecord::Base, then try the Array and finally try whatever :arel leads to. Assuming I found the right spot in the code. Thanks for the info. I'll definitely check out Herd.

Comment: some experimentation shows that rails is clever about what `all` means -- so, this sort of thing behaves as one might expect for class methods which call `all`. it would be nice to see some documentation or code explaining in which circumstances the magic behavior took effect.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the following question for now:

> Why do messages sent to an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation
>   cause methods on the Product class object to get invoked?

`ActiveRecord::Relation` class is used to chain several methods without actually trigger multiple SQL queries. This way you can write something like `Product.where('price <= ?', 100).order(:price).limit(30)` and Rails will execute just one query.

The magic works because you have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance until you try to access the data (e.g. because a `first` or `all` call), at that time the query will be run and you'll have `ActiveRecord::Base` or one of his descendants.

Long story short, if you check the class with `@products.class` you'll see is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` but later you have `Product` instances, and then you can call the `to_csv` method.

Comment: I understand that instances of ActiveRecord::Relation represent part or all of a SQL query, and that calling first or all on one causes the query to execute and create an Array of (in this case) instances of class Product. That doesn't explain how sending the to_csv message to an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation leads to the **class method** to_csv() getting called.