# Exporting CSV in Rails with a class method being called on an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

I want to export a csv file from Rails and I'm following the Railscast on this topic (http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast).

In the Railscast, the controller (products_controller.rb) contains:

```
    def index
      @products = Product.order(:name)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
      end
    end
```

The Product model (models/product.rb) contains:

```
    def self.to_csv
      CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |product|
          csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end
```

As seen in this StackOverflow question ([Exporting CSV data from Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661854/exporting-csv-data-from-rails)), to_csv is a class method that is being called on an array of class objects. I expected this to fail because to_csv is not being called on the Product class.

This works, but why does it work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Self is your model, Product in your case. The method .to_csv is a class method. You call the method .to_csv on the class Product, what part seems odd to you?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't articulate my confusion very clearly. I was expecting something like `Product.to_csv(@products)` instead of `@products.to_csv` in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question should have been "Why would sending the message, to_csv, to an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation cause a method on the Product class object to be invoked?"

In Rails, class methods automatically become available as "collection" methods; This is the reason why they are available to Relation objects (See this SO question/answer I missed earlier: [how does this Ruby class method get invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587711/how-does-this-ruby-class-method-get-invoked?rq=1)).

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct - you are *sending* the message `to_csv` to an instance of, initially `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which ultimately is transformed into `Array`.

Have you required `csv`? If so, sending `to_csv` to an instance of an `Array` will work.

The `stdlib/csv` library decorates `Array` - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/Array.html